# Replace matrix elements with vector MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following string matrix:

```
encodedData=[1 0 1 1]
```

I want to create a new Matrix "mananalog" replacing encodedData items= 1's with [1 1 1 1] and 0's with [-1 -1 -1 -1]

Final matrix mananalog would be: [1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]

I've tried using the following code:

```
mananalog(find(encodedData=='0'))=[num2str(1*(-Vd)) num2str(1*(-Vd)) num2str(1*(-Vd)) num2str(1*(-Vd))];
mananalog(find(encodedData=='1'))=[num2str(1*(Vd)) num2str(1*(Vd)) num2str(1*(Vd)) num2str(1*(Vd))];
```

## vd=0.7

Nevertheless, i have the following error:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
```

Do you know the function so as to do this? (Not using for)

Comment: Is it a string or an array? What do you get if you type `+encodedData` in MATLAB?

Comment: @StewieGriffin encodedData is a char matrix [1001001001001100101010...]

Comment: what's the content of `Vd`?

Comment: What exactly do you get if you type: `+encodedData(1:4)`? It would be very helpful if you supplied that information... :)

Comment: @bushmills Vd=0.7

Comment: @StewieGriffin [49 48 48 49]  ... ASCII

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`regexprep`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexprep.html) or [`strrep`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) like this:

```
encodedData='1 0 1 1'
regexprep(regexprep(encodedData, '1', '1 1 1 1'),'0','-1 -1 -1 -1')
ans =
1 1 1 1 -1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

It's a bit simpler if you use two lines though:

```
encodedDataExpanded = regexprep(encodedData, '1', '1 1 1 1');
encodedDataExpanded = regexprep(encodedDataExpanded , '0', '-1 -1 -1 -1')
```

This will first search for the character `'1'` in the string, and replace it with the string: `'1 1 1 1'`. Then it search for `'0'` and replaces it with the string `'-1 -1 -1 -1'`.

With integers, not characters:

```
encodedData = [1 0 1 1];
reshape(bsxfun(@minus, 2*encodedData, ones(4,1)), 1, [])
ans =    
   1   1   1   1  -1  -1  -1  -1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
```

And, if you have MATLAB R2015a or later then there's [`repelem`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/repelem.html) as Luis mentioned in a comment:

```
repelem(2*encodedData-1, 4)
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!!

Comment: Do you know the way to do this using int numbers instead of string? I mean that final matrix would consists of integer numbers.

Comment: I've tried using regexprep but it only works with string

Comment: Awesome implementation! ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to convert between strings and numerics, you can also do

```
>> kron(encodedData, ones(1,4)) + kron(1-encodedData, -ones(1,4))
```

Comment: Yes, that was silly of me.  `repelem` is definitely the way to go here.